# I need a Wordpress folder to NOT be case sensitive without writing 200 redirects

Tags: linux, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a blog set up at [blog.ftj.com/ACSM](http://blog.ftj.com/ACSM/), it is hosted with Bluehost and their folder structures seem to be case sensitive.  Is there something in the .htaccess file that I can adjust so that all possible combinations get redirected to the specific uppercase URL.

Another issue is that it seems that I need to redirect

> blog.ftj.com/acsm/

with and without the forward slash.

Here is my current .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ACSM/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /ACSM/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Please submit the full change if you would.

Comment: Welcome to the world of \*nix.  Windows is actually the exception in being case insensitive.  You can easily set up case insensitive rules for specific directories as in Stasik's answer, but leave all case handling of parameters to `index.php`.

Comment: @TerryE, can you give me an example, I'm very green with this.

Comment: Jon, as I said Stasik's ans is pretty much there re directories.  Case insensitive matching of parameters in WordPress would require mods to the WP code.  Not a good idea if you are "very green at this".

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the following .htaccess in the root dir to rewrite all requests to /ACSM into /acsm

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/acsm$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ACSM [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/acsm/(.*)$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^acsm/(.*)$ /ACSM/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Sorry for delays, have not got an Apache at hands....

Comment: Stasik, Rule 1 target should be `/ACSM`, and rule 2 won't work in an `.htaccess` context.  You need to drop the leading / on the regexp.  Also add a `RewriteBase /` before the first cond.  :-)

Comment: is it correct now? thank you! As I told already, no Apache at hands :(. Well, one can drop R=301 to avoid the redirect!

Comment: Stasik, +1 on dropping the 301s.  These could be internal redirects.  But if you're going to build up reputation in this area, then its best to have HTTP Server at hand to try your answers out -- even if in a VM on your PC :-)